# Is it possible to connect two wireless range extenders?

Tags: wireless-router

Hello i have tplink tlwr 740n router and tlwa-850re range extender connected together but my house is surrounded with thick walls so even range extender is loosing signal.So i'm planning to buy another wireless range extender.My doubt is can i connect two wireless range extenders together??because router has qss/wps functionality so i connected one router with one range extender.Now i want to connect my second range extender with first range extender is it possible???

Comment: did you read the manual or try google?  One google and I knew the answer in 20 seconds.

Comment: Sounds like time to run some wires.

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/457569/setting-up-wifi-extenders-is-it-possible-to-daisy-chain-them

Comment: @Bigbio2002 If only we could flag items as cross-site duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

Go with powerline range extenders? I have 2 in my place and they work fine.
You just join whichever wifi is strongest in the area.

Most have a built in ethernet too, handy for wired connections.

This is a good scalable method.

You may have to change the IP of one of them, if the want a fixed IP, but you can normally configure that in the settings of the extender.

Oh, you can also unplug the extender and move to another outlet if you need to change location, very handy.

Comment: Just do yourself a favor and make sure to get AV2 devices. You will probably not be happy with devices with a nameplate speed of less than 1200 Mbps. (Because they won't actually provide anywhere near a tenth of that.)